# Theoretical values of radius and mass of O9.5 II star

Tags: star, stellar-astrophysics

Where to find please theoretical values of radius and mass of O9.5 II star?

I mean something like in [this article](http://www.mpe.mpg.de/~martins/pub/calib_Ostar.pdf). However, there are only O I, O III and O V stars in this article.

Comment: Search for O9.5II stars came up with Mintaka Aa as an example, the paper linked on SIMBAD for the spectral type ([Shenar et al. 2015](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/809/2/135/meta)), section 4.1 just takes the average of the O9.5III and O9.5I properties from the linked article.

Comment: Thank you very much